# Xcode doesn't find openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions: FacebookSDK for iOS method

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to upgrade the facebook sdk for iOS from 3.0 to 3.1.1. I've added the new FacebookSDK. I suppose that I did it correctly, it's easy... Installing the downloaded FacebookSDK-3.1.1.pkg and drag&drop facebook.framework and FacebookSDKResources.bundle to the frameworks of the project.

I'm trying to use openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions: method but when I build the project I get the message "No known class method for selector 'openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:"

I don't know why because if I check the FacebookSDK.framework headers I can see the openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions: in the FBSession.h class...

I've cleaned the Build Folder, the derived data folder, the os x caches,...

What is happening?

Thanks a lot,

Carlos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that FacebookSDK.framework had been copied previously in the project folder. So, Xcode found the old framework on the project folder.

Solution: deleting the FacebookSDK.framework from the project folder.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the upgrade was not clean as it appears to be picking up an older version. Go ahead and delete the ~/Documents/FacebookSDK folder, then re-install the package.

The other thing to check is your framework search path. In Xcode, go to the project navigator, select your project, select the target, then click on Build Settings and search for Frameworks Search Paths. See if it's point to where you expect your framework to be.

Comment: Thanks a lot C. Abernathy. The solution has been different from yours, but you gave the idea of checking if the old framework was in another place...